# On Database first, is there a way to implement your own startup migration

Tags: c#, .net, database, startup

At my current company we use a DB first approach, and after coming from a code first background, one thing I very much miss is automatic database migrations and db source control.

Without modifying tables and views (because it is dependent on the edmx) is there a best practice to implement something similar, except it seeds the db?  I would want it to quickly/efficiently modify config tables and CRUD stored procs without impacting startup UNLESS it needed to actually modify something.

Comment: you can always cheat and generate CodeFirst classes from database and use CodeFirst

Comment: Ha, I tried that, but the others here prefer to stay with what they have already.  So the only option I have is to either modify the database manually or see if I can persuade them to add a layer that updates/seed the db data (excluding schema)